# "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__UserRights__0155B971'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.UserRights'. error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi im trying to update operation  But while updating it showing error near to db. save changes().

its shows the error which is mention below

An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

So i searched in inner exception. it shows the error which is mention below.

"Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__UserRights__0155B971'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.UserRights'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

My Controller code

```
   public ActionResult UsetBasedAuthenticationEditSave(UserAuthenticationViewModel objuavm )
    {
        ViewBag.UserID = new SelectList(db.UserDetails, "UserID", "UserName", objuavm.UserID);
        ViewBag.ModuleID = new SelectList(db.UserModules, "ModuleID", "ModuleName", objuavm.ModuleID);
        ViewBag.SubModule = new SelectList(db.UserModules, "SubModule", "SubModule", objuavm.SubModule);

        var objuserrightsresult = db.UserRights.Find(objuavm.UserRitsID);
        if(objuserrightsresult!=null)
        {
            objuserrightsresult.UserID = objuavm.UserID;
            objuserrightsresult. ModuleID = objuavm.ModuleID;
            objuserrightsresult. Toview = Convert.ToBoolean(objuavm.Toview);
            objuserrightsresult. ToAdd = Convert.ToBoolean(objuavm.ToAdd);
            objuserrightsresult. ToEdit = Convert.ToBoolean(objuavm.ToEdit);
            objuserrightsresult. ToDelete = Convert.ToBoolean(objuavm.ToDelete);
            objuserrightsresult.IsActive = Convert.ToBoolean(objuavm.IsActive);
            objuserrightsresult.IsDeleted = Convert.ToBoolean(objuavm.IsDeleted);
            objuserrightsresult. EditedDate = DateTime.Now;
            objuserrightsresult. LastActiveOn = DateTime.Now;
            objuserrightsresult. RowID = Guid.NewGuid();
            objuserrightsresult. CreatedSeesionID = Guid.NewGuid();
            objuserrightsresult. EditedSessionID = Guid.NewGuid();
            objuserrightsresult. OfflineMode = false;
            objuserrightsresult.OfflineID = Guid.NewGuid();
            objuserrightsresult.SubModule = objuavm.SubModule;
            db.UserRights.Add(objuserrightsresult);
           }
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("UserBasedAuthenticationIndex");
    }
```

Comment: You adding an existing entity. You just need to update it (remove the line `db.UserRights.Add(objuserrightsresult);`)

Comment: ok stephen lets i have a try

Comment: Stephen its working can you explain me what mistake i did

Comment: Your getting an existing entity using `db.UserRights.Find(objuavm.UserRitsID);` and its being tracked by the context, so when you update its properties you just need to call `SaveChanges()` (you cant add it again because it already exists). See also the answer added by Rosdi Kasim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment this line:

```
//db.UserRights.Add(objuserrightsresult);
```

Since you are doing UPDATE, you should not add it again... just update the fields value and then just call `db.SaveChanges();`